BenchmarkDotNet MemoryDiagnoser
I have some code that I want to try to speed up. It doesn't do much memory allocation, but it could certainly be improved. However, to reduce the memory allocations will require a LOT of refactoring.
Before I perform this work, I was wondering if there was a way using the MemoryDiagnoser that I can see how much time is currently being spent performing the allocations? so I can gauge whether its actually worth the effort? or even accounts for any reasonable time in the first place.
For example, with a method marked as [Benchmark] and the class with [MemoryDiagnoser] can it tell me how much time was spent allocating memory vs actually doing work?

The MemorydDiagnoser does not measure allocation time just allocation size as far as I know.

Highly suggested blog post about this topic
